# ¿Como serializar y deserealizar un objeto en el cual contiene un bitmap?

Tags: c#, serialización

tengo un problema, tengo una clase en la cual contiene un comando y/o un bitmap de una captura de pantalla y lo que necesito es enviarla al cliente por medio de un networkstream, el problema es que he tratado de hacerlo con BinaryFormatter pero este me dice que ya esta descontinuado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que se puede hacer con BinaryWriter y BinaryReader pero estos solo leen y escriben Bytes[] por lo cual no se si funcione como quiero ya que tengo que convertir manualmente el objeto en un arreglo de bytes y viceversa, como puedo serializar mi objeto de manera correcta???

esta es mi clase

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;


namespace ServerMessage
{
public enum Command
{
    CloseConnection,
    Image,
    Input
} 

[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public Command Command { get; set; }
    public Bitmap bitmap { get; set; }

    static BinaryFormatter BinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    public T DesSerialize<T>(NetworkStream Stream)
    {
        return (T)BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream);
    }

    public void Serialize(NetworkStream Stream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream, this);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide#preferred-alternatives) sugiere que uses otro tipo de serialización. Por ejemplo `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` con XML o JSON.

Suponiendo que no te interesa usar XML ni JSON, puedes crear funciones que escriban y lean variable por variable con `BinaryReader` y `BinaryWriter`. Ten en cuenta que solo aceptan tipos primitivos.

Por lo tanto, para otros tipos como un Bitmap deberías implementar una forma de convertirlo a bytes. Por ejemplo, [guardando](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) el Bitmap como un archivo temporal y leyendo los bytes del archivo.

Mi idea es hacer algo así:

```
public class Persona
{
    string nombre;
    int edad;

    public Persona(string nombre, int edad)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void Serialize(Stream stream)
    {
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(nombre);
        writer.Write(edad);
    }

    public static Persona Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        string nombre;
        int edad;

        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        nombre = reader.ReadString();
        edad = reader.ReadInt32();

        return new Persona(nombre, edad);
    }
}
```